# Any experience of Scanning Services?

Tags: scanning, scanning-service, service-recommendation

I would like to get all my old slides and negatives converted to digital.
There is no way that a clutz like me is going to make a good job of doing this myself.

I have about 3000 images to convert.

- Has anyone had any experience with scanning services?
- Can you recommend one?  (Or warn me away from any bad ones!)
- In particular, can you recommend a service in the UK?

Comment: Couldn't that question be merged with this one: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5192/whats-the-best-way-to-scan-in-hundreds-of-pictures

Comment: @sebastien: Given that there is a bounty on this question, I am hesitant to merge it right now. I have never merged a question with a bounty before, and I am unsure what effect it would have. I'll see if I can get some insight from one of the SE mods about mergers and bounty.

Comment: I think that the questions are different - Billy ONeal is asking more generally how to approach the task of digitising negs/slides/prints, while I am asking specifically about scanning services.  I realise they are related, but I don't think they are the same.

Comment: I agree, AJ. I don't see any reason to do any merging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've only used them for a minimal amount of work myself but know of LOTS of folks who have had large collections scanned by [ScanCafe](http://www.scancafe.com/).  I can't speak to their availability for the UK.

Comment: Thanks, @ahockley.  I have looked at ScanCafe (largely as a result of being bombarded with ads on PhotoFocus!), but unfortunately they only work in North America.  :(

Comment: You should be aware, AJ, that the bounty will automatically be rewarded to the selected answer when it ends. Since ahockley's answer is currently selected as the correct answer, it will get the bounty. If there are other answers, and you find one more appropriate, make sure you change the selected answer to reward the bounty to the appropriate person.