# What's the best way to scan in hundreds of pictures?

Tags: scanning, automation

I have thousands of old pictures which were sitting in a photo album. Unfortunately, instead of the photo album protecting the pictures, the plastic coverings yellowed, and the pictures themselves had to be carefully extracted from the books. There is also quite a bit of powdered paper (the backings on the books pretty much fell apart while we extracted the pictures), and the fronts of the images are still a bit sticky.

These pictures are 30+ years old, are often extremely faded, and were originally taken on (what I think is) "110 film" -- they are approximately 2.5" squares.

Anyway, I need to scan all these images in to preserve them from further decay. Unfortunately, it's taking forever -- going through less than 100 images took an entire day, even if one discounts any time spent in Photoshop trying to remove some of the photo album's artifacts on the images.

What I really need is some method of scanning the images in *faster*. Most automated solutions aren't going to work because they accept 4x6s as their smallest image size, and even if that was not the case, the adhesives still stuck to the prints would probably ruin any such device in 5 seconds flat.

Is there a better way of doing this (i.e. fast scanner?) that wouldn't take so much time?

Comment: Have you got the negatives still? You'll generally get a better result from scanning those, rather than the prints.

Comment: @Rowland: No, I don't, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you give us a sense of what your budget is?

Comment: @Reid: "Poor" college student. As cheap as humanly possible :P

Comment: Judging by the size and shape, they were probably taken on 120 or 220 film (56mm variable aspect), not 110 (5"x4" until 1929; 13x17mm since 1972).

Comment: @Imre: I don't think "110" means "110mm" -- it's smaller than 35mm film. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/110_film

Comment: @BillyONeal yes, I meant that same "110 film" you are linking to (the Wikipedia article also links to the older roll-format film with same number).

Comment: @Imre: I'm confused. It looks like both 120 and 220 are medium format films; these images are certainly not taken on medium format (they're small and very grainy).

Comment: Well, I did not know about the grainy part :) 60x60mm (i.e. roughly 2½") squares are a common square format shot on 120/220, so I suspected you'd have contact prints from those.

Comment: @Imre: Why would one use medium format for images so small?

Comment: Why would anyone use such a small format at all? Cataloging might be an answer. The contact prints can be made without using an enlarger and could have been used to select images for larger prints.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do you have money to throw at the problem? Because the fastest way is undoubtedly to *have someone else do it*. And there are plenty of services just waiting to take your business. [ScanCafe](http://www.scancafe.com/) is one, but there's others as well, almost certainly including your local photo shop.

Comment: +1 I came in here to say that! The only real way to speed the process up is to have it done for you.

Comment: +1 I would check DigMyPics too (here is what they have to say about their ScanCafe, to be taken with a grain of salt, http://www.digmypics.com/getTheRealTruth.aspx, and vice-versa: http://www.scancafe.com/pricing/pricecomparison)

Comment: Another vote, services that convert analog formats (photos, videos) are betting more and more common. Probably you'll may even find a local shop near you that will do the job

Comment: Can anyone recommend a specific service (that's available in the UK)?  (http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/any-experience-of-scanning-services)

Comment: Have a "green bent angle thing" by popular demand.

Comment: I'm about to send some stuff to scan, here is one more review I found online, comparing ScanCafe, DigMyPics and ScanDigital (https://www.macworld.com/article/143504/2009/10/outsourcescanning.html), another one of ScanCafe (http://www.michaelmiles.com/2010/06/25/scancafe-review/) and a top #10 (http://photo-scanning-services.com/digmypics-review.html)

Answer (score 10):

I did this last year, using equipment I already owned - tripod, DSLR and a macro lens - rather than buying a scanner. I used a little lightbox for negatives and soft diffused daylight for prints. I wrote up my experiences on a flickr thread that can be seen [here](http://www.flickr.com/groups/canondslr/discuss/72157620448786604). I managed to get through about a hundred an hour without much difficulty.

Comment: By the way, 110 was miniscule, rectangular, and quite poor quality. Your prints sound like they're contact prints from much larger negatives.

Comment: This is definitely the best DIY option.  Once you're set up you can scan in the time it takes you to load a normal scanner.

Answer (score 4):

If you have some time on your hands, but have lots of photos, you can save money by doing the scanning yourself. You can either use free image editor tools to crop and save the individual images (after scanning multiple images per go) or you can try [AutoSplitter](http://autosplitter.com/).
This simple Windows utility will do the painful splitting and cropping task automatically for you. You can also adjust manually, should it be necessary.

Edit: yes, I'm the author - created the software after having the same problem.

Comment: This seems awfully like an advertisement. Are you affiliated with this software? If so, that's okay, but you need to disclose that connection.

Answer (score 3):

Use a high speed page feed scanner like the [DR-2010C](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/office/products/hardware/scanners/high_speed_document_scanners/imageformula_dr_2010c_compact_color_scanner#Overview) from Canon. It can scan up to 20 pages per minute and automatically crops the scan image to the document size. You can get it from $370- from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0010OSE62) (amongst others)

If you have thousands of photos to scan it will be cheaper to buy this scanner than to use a service like Scancafe. 1680 photos at Scancafe will cost $370-. If you factor in your selling price your breakeven point will drop to about 1000 photos.

Comment: Is it capable of scanning the 2" squares that I mention in my question? Will it be broken by the adhesives I mentioned in my question?

Comment: It can handle a minimum size of 1.9" Width and 2.1" Height so it should work for you. I have worked with the DR series of page feed scanners, using them for document and label scanning. In my experience they are robust and high quality. They should easily handle your prints. From time to time you will need to clean the rollers and platens with isopropyl alcohol.

Answer (score 2):

Sort through the photos to identify the rarest, most precious photos, and scan these (or get them scanned) on a flatbed scanner. Slow, but will give the best quality.

For the rest, try Pic Scanner app for iPhone and iPad. It scans, auto-crops and saves photos, and is [very easy to use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VONIBPw3f4Q). The [free download](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pic-scanner/id644278663) allows 10 scans to try out the app, then a $2.99 purchase is needed for unlimited scanning and sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion: **wait until you have money to throw at the problem.** It's probably not too difficult to change the storage method now to minimize further deterioration, and then either save / wait until you have a better income / find a relative with money for the next few years and then do it.